# WordPress custom post types are showing under archives/blog? But I don't want them to?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

http://weddings.agapewith.us/photos/caleb-promise

Notice the page appears under blog. They are a custom post-type of photos so I want to show each posting as children of photos. What is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing is using conditionals to figure out if the item was a custom-post-type and if so a CSS class is added to the body. Using the CSS class I un-highlighted the blog and highlighted the post-type-parent

Answer (score 0):

The class "current_page_parent" is currently attached to the Blog menu item.  Can you move it to the Photo menu item as I've done below?  This should fix your problem.

```
   <li id="menu-item-18" class="nav-photos menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-18"><a href="http://weddings.agapewith.us/photo">Photo</a></li> 

   <li id="menu-item-149" class="current_page_parent nav-blog menu-item menu-item-type-post_type current_page_parent menu-item-149"><a href="http://weddings.agapewith.us/blog">Blog</a></li>
```

1. Remove "current_page_parent" from the "Blog" li class.
2. Insert "current_page_parent" on the "Photo" li class.

The CSS styling for the menu items is determined by the numarous class names that are bound to the menus.  By moving them around, you effectively apply different CSS rules to different elements.

Comment: It's a WordPress site, I don't set the CSS classes, WordPress does